# How to make grep match \1 \2 e.t.c in search string

Tags: bash, search, grep, escaping, backreference

I tried following code to make grep search for \2
But grep fails to find the matching string in test file. I am running cygwin.

```
C:\test 19# val="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise"

C:\test 20# escval="$(echo "$value" | sed -r 's,\\,\\\\,g')"

C:\test 20# echo $escval
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Enterprise

C:\test 21# echo "export DIR=\"${val}\"" > testdata

C:\test 22# cat testdata
export DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise"

C:\test 23# cat testdata | grep -E  "^[[:space:]]*export[[:space:]]+${key}=\"${val}\""; echo $?
grep: Invalid back reference
2

C:\test 24# cat testdata |  grep -E "^[[:space:]]*export[[:space:]]+${key}=\"${escval}\""; echo $?
1

C:\test 25# grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 3.0
Packaged by Cygwin (3.0-2)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
```

Trying with fixed strings is not an option since the actual expression..

Updates: I tried all escaping too and i have modified my question.

Comment: why are you using `grep -E` for a string? `-E` does not mean "expression", it means "extended regex". `-e` means "expression"

Comment: with or without E i have the same result...I used it because the actual code has some regex too..I have only simplified the steps.

Comment: I saw teds answer and have modified the grep... -F(fixed strings) does not work because -E and -F and exclusive...As for escaping it somehow did not work if i use -E option...without -E it does work.

Comment: I just updated the testdata from actual...Added export e.t.c

Comment: Yes i need whole line.

Comment: yes following works. cat testdata |  grep -E "^[[:space:]]*export[[:space:]]+${key}=" | grep \"${escval}\" ; echo $?   i.e splitting grep into two greps.

Comment: I need -E because first part is reg ex....i.e cat testdata |  grep "^[[:space:]]*export[[:space:]]+${key}=" | grep \"${escval}\" ; echo $? where I removed -E from first grep DOES NOT work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape *all* the backslashes, not only the one before the number (`2`) and with the updated question in which extended regular expressions are really needed, you need to escape `(` and `)` too. In fact, escape everything but alphanumeric characters to be sure:

```
$ escval="$(echo "$val" | sed -E 's,([^[:alnum:]]),\\\1,g')"
$ echo "${escval}"
C\:\\Program\ Files\ \(x86\)\\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\\2019\\Enterprise
$ grep -E "^\s*export\s+${key}=\"${escval}\"" testdata ; echo $?
export DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise"
0
```

Note: I use `\s` instead of the character class matching on `[[:space:]]`. It's shorter and I find it easier to read.

Comment: the fixed strings option though attractive can not be used because in my case is is complex reg expression and -E and -F and mutually exclusive.As for escaping i tried following in my actual example

Comment: I have modified the question a bit to more close to actual.

Comment: Based on suggestions... following works  cat testdata |  grep -E "^[[:space:]]*export[[:space:]]+${key}=" | grep \"${escval}\" ; echo $?